# Match the number of inserted field with dynamically inserted text boxes

Tags: php, session

book.php

```
<input type="text" id="total_seats" name="total_seats" value="" readonly /></td>
```

view.php

```
<?php
   $serial_no = 1;
$seats = explode(',', $_SESSION['total_seats']);
foreach ($seats as $seat) { ?>
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $serial_no++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $seat; ?> </td>
           <td><input type="text" name="passenger_name[]" style="border:1px solid #000;" required /></td>

        </tr>
```

In book.php page, the total_seats contains the number of seats inserted through checkboxes,  this code runs totally fine but when i check 3 check boxes & the total_seats contain 3 seat numbers, its showing 4 text fields along with serial number upto 4 in my view.php page.. how do i match my seat number with my input total_seats without one extra field ..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please further explain `total_seats contains the number of seats inserted through checkboxes` I believe that is where your error is.

Comment: look i ve a online booking site, when i chekc a chek box the no of the check box got displayed in the field total_seats

Comment: Can you share how you are populating $_SESSION['total_seats']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this kind of stuff happen in your case (one more ',' in the end of string), so you have extra one empty element in the end:

```
$seats = explode(".", "a,b,c,d,");

print_r($seats);

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => 
)
```

Edit: update with solution for this case - use `rtrim()` to remove last comma

```
$total_seats = $_SESSION['total_seats'];
$seats = explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ",")); // cut trailing commas
foreach ($seats as $seat){
  .. below are the same
```

Comment: So, print out your $_SESSION['total_seats'] first and add code to get rid of last ',' if that's the case.

Comment: i got ur point... i ve an extra comma that's why m getting 1 extra field right ???

Comment: Just edited, you could use rtrim() to remove unnecessary comma

Comment: Thank u thank u thank u .. its fixed.. thank u so so so much ... _/\_ .. Namaste .. thank u

Comment: lo check this question plz   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160012/daywise-search-from-the-datepicker?noredirect=1#comment30050875_20160012

Answer (score 0):

I am 90% sure that your problem here is with `total_seats contains the number of seats inserted through checkboxes` the rest of the code should work as it stands. What I think you are doing is adding `#,` to the total_seats value for each checkbox you check. With explode, if you have four values and 4 commas such as `"1,2,3,4,"` then you will have five values:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

be sure not to include the last comma after your last seat #

Comment: yeah for the last comma i mgetting that extra field.. how can i remove that ??