# Daywise search from the datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

form.php

```
<form action="search_bus.php" id="search_form1" style="padding:10px;">
    <div class="left"><b>Leaving From</b><br /><input type="text" name="source_point" id="source_point"/></div>
    <div class="right"><b>Going To</b><br /><input type="text" name="destination" id="destination"/></div>
    <div class="dt"> 
        Date of Journey <input id="datepick" size="19" name="datepick" class="text_box2" title="Departure Date" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepick" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
        });
    </script>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my form, when I search a bus through it, whatever date I give,it's showing me the bus from my database(searchiing by it's source point and destination_point), but I've inserted available days for the buses. i want to search the buses according to it's respective days. That means when I'm entering a date in my datepicker, it should search it's corresponding day from the database and show the result, if in that day, the bus is not available, it should not display any result.

search.php

```
<?php
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
    {
?>

<td><input name="bus_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['bus_name'];?>" class="input_box" />
```

Comment: why not use input type="date" ??

Comment: @iamde_coder input type="date" only works for chrome not  in any other browser

Comment: ve updated my question @dianuj

Answer (score 1):

we really need to see your server side code and the data structure to determine this.

ideally you would want to capture the date range(s) then adjust your SQL statement to only return the values based on that.

$datepick would be your value from your form probably a cleaned $_POST['datepicke'];

this would make is from 12:00AM on the date till 12:00AM the next date so within one day

> example SQL: "SELECT * FROM bus WHERE departure => $datepick AND
>   departure <= DATE_ADD($datepick, INTERVAL 1 DAY)"

hope that helps

Comment: I ve updated my question .. i ve inserted my days in yes no format in chekcboxes to database...

Comment: & may be a bus is available for consecutively 3days & for the rest days its not.. what should i do for that??

Comment: it would really help to see your data schema. what exactly are you checking in the database for availability? If it is something like Monday - Friday then the query I gave you earlier wouldn't work you would need to determine if a date is a specific day.

I suggest PHP for this. by checking if the date is a specific day with something like this
date('w',$datefromdatabase);
w - A numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday)

Comment: look , take a bus no 1 which is only available in sunday monday & firday & bus no 2 available in tuesday, wednesday & saturday .. thus i want to search a bus according to it's corresponding day.. i mean if an user enters a date it should search it's corresponding day & show the result ... if in that date the bus is not available according to it's day, it should display no result

Comment: [code]//pseudocode

assuming you have sunday-saturday as fields in the database with values of 1 or 0


$day = date('w',$_POST['datepick']) //departure_date from form

switch($day){
    case(0):
        $datecheck = sunday = 1;
    break;
    case(1):
    $datecheck = monday =1;
... //continue for rest of days
}

"SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]' && $datecheck"

this way the only results that are returned are the ones where that departure day is a value of 1 in the database.[/code]